# How would I target an id within a class in LESS?

Tags: css, less

Relatively new to LESS and trying out how nesting works. I have read the things on the less page.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head class="Setup">
    <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="../LESS/core.less"/>
</head>
<div class="Test">
    <span id="Test1" class="Test2"></span>
</div>
</html>
```

LESS

```
.Test2 {
    display: block;
    #Test1 {
        .background1;
        width: 40px;
        height: 1000px !important;
    }
}
```

but if I were to write it without the nesting it works

```
.Test2 {
    display: block;
}

#Test1 {
    .background1;
    width: 40px;
    height: 1000px !important;
}
```

.background is just {background: red;}. Is the concept just messed up in my head?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Nesting Issues and Mismatched Markup**

Nesting generally indicates that a particular element will appear beneath another element, so your current code has the right idea.

Currently your nesting example would attempt to target an element with an `id` of "Test1" that was nested below an element with the class "Test2", which isn't the same as your markup.

If you wanted to use the same markup to target your element, consider changing your outermost `.Test2` selector to `.Test` instead :

```
/* This will target an element with id "Test`" below an element with class "Test" */
.Test {
    display: block;
    #Test1 {
        width: 40px;
        height: 1000px !important;
    }
}
```

You can see how this is translated to CSS below :

[image]

**Background Check Your Syntax**

Additionally, there appears to be an issue with your `.background` selector that you were using. Did you mean to target an additional style below your "Test2" element like the following example?

```
.Test {
    display: block;
    #Test1 {
        .background{
          width: 40px;
          height: 1000px !important;
        }
    }
}
```

which would compile as follows :

[image]

Comment: the .background1 is just a mix in I added

    .background1 {
        background: red;
    }

and thanks this helped clear up my head

Comment: Ah. I wasn't quite sure as I didn't see the definition for it, so I assumed it was a typo.